# Forge DA4R memory limit exceeded

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm trying to create a plugin on Forge with DA4R V3.

For small Revit files it's working fine but with larger (like 300mb) I got this log report :

```
[07/25/2020 10:59:06] Initializing RCE....
[07/25/2020 10:59:06] Initializing RevitCoreEngine (and possibly running stub installer)...
[07/25/2020 10:59:09] Initialize and  get RCE: (VersionBuild) 19.0.0.0 (VersionNumber) 2019 (SubVersionNumber) 2019.2
[07/25/2020 11:58:00] ERROR: The process memory limit exceeded (2944).
[07/25/2020 12:00:10] End Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[07/25/2020 12:00:10] Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code -1073740791 which indicates an error.
[07/25/2020 12:00:10] End script phase.
[07/25/2020 12:00:10] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
```

But I didn't find any way to increase the memory available, is there a specific way to do it ?

Comment: hmm i don't think the c# language tag is needed here - maybe remove it?

Comment: Hi, 
Unfortunately, this not possible set Memory limits, may I know the workItem id? objective of your addin ? just to understand for us why it is failing for this revit file.

You can reply here or write to Forge Help <forge[dot]help[at]autodesk.com>

Comment: @sommmen indeed, I added the tag cause my add-in is in c# but the error isn't c# related. My bad.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I am running into the same error, and it seems, so far to be files "Zipped by BIM 360" that are over 4 GB. But only 2 files trigging this error so far.

Comment: @BretThompson - do you have a workItem Id for us to troubleshoot and do some diagnostics ?

Comment: @MadhukarMoogala, I sent a full log of one of these workitems to forge[dot]help[at]autodesk.com and it was assigned request #7186. Will that work?

Comment: @BretThompson the details and logs I gave by mail have been forwarded to the engineer team of Design Automation. I'm waiting for any updates and I'll post back here as soon as I got them.

Comment: @BretThompson - can you let us know how big are failing Revit files and what API you call on these files ?

Comment: @MadhukarMoogala, The specific RVT files that are getting opened in Revit are in the range of 400MB to 500MB, but these files are delivered to Design Automation from Document Management in a ZIP file that is just over 4GB.